# Python - Merge dataframes where column contains a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm using Python Pandas to merge two dataframe, like so:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, 'inner', left_on='Zip_Code', right_on='Zip_Code_List')
```

However, I would like to do this ONLY where another column ('Business_Name') in df2 contains a certain value. How do I do this? So, something like, "When Business Name is Walmart, merge these two dataframes."

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2[df2['Business_Name'] == 'Walmart'], how='inner', left_on='Zip_Code', right_on='Zip_Code_List')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#you can filter on df2 first and then merge.
pd.merge(df1, df2.query("Business_Name' == 'Walmart'"), how='inner', left_on='Zip_Code', right_on='Zip_Code_List')
```